# Json string limit

Tags: ios, json, limit

I am working on an iPhone app which runs remote queries on my db and displays them in a table view. I have a PHP script which fetches the data and encodes it in Json to be downloaded in Xcode. Right now, my app works for smaller queries but but not for larger ones.

When I was researching my issue, I read a few posts about Json issues with the length limit of the content of a string. I am not sure I 100% grasp the concept though... Right now, for small outputs, it displays everything properly, but for large ones it displays an empty table. When I print out all the fields of any one of my element (ex Name, Address, City) those values are always null (for the large queries).

Can anyone explain how the length of my string affects my fields and how would I go about fixing it? I saw some solutions online (such as breaking up the string) but since I do not yet fully understand the problem I didn't want to rush into things. Any explanation would be great.

I have attached the code for convenience (from the tutorial http://codewithchris.com/iphone-app-connect-to-mysql-database/):

```
 @interface HomeModel()
    {
        NSMutableData *_downloadedData;
        }
        @end

        @implementation HomeModel

        - (void)downloadItems
        {

          // Download the json file
            NSURL *jsonFileUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/www/service.php"];


          // Create the request
            NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:jsonFileUrl];

           // Create the NSURLConnection
            [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:urlRequest delegate:self];
        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
        {
           // Initialize the data object
            _downloadedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
        }

        - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
        {
           // Append the newly downloaded data
            [_downloadedData appendData:data];
        }

        - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
        {
            // Create an array to store the locations
            NSMutableArray *_locations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            // Parse the JSON that came in
            NSError *error;
            NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:_downloadedData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
            NSLog(@"JSON IS %@.", jsonArray);

        // This log prints it out fine

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++){

               NSDictionary *jsonElement = jsonArray[i];
               Location *newLocation = [[Location alloc] init];
               newLocation.name = jsonElement[@"name"];


               NSLog(@"PRINTING project_id %@", jsonElement[@"name"]);
            //Here the log will print out NULL
    ...
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I suspect your JSON is invalid for bigger values, put `NSLog(@"%@",[[NSString alloc] initWithData: _downloadedData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);` and copy paste the output to some json validator online service like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: I just tried it and the json was valid. I purposefully tried with a huge query (15385 results).

Comment: This is why I am so confused by the string limit...

Comment: update your question with jsonArray result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my problem. It wasn't related to the json, which was properly formatted all along. My issue had to do with how I was storing the fields and printing them out, sorry. Thank you for the  help.